# Legacy application unreachable code

Tags: java

I am debugging one legacy J2EE application I and think I found some dead code and some redundant condition checks. Please give me your thoughts on my observations i.e. if they are valid. Please note that I am not permitted to rewrite this block, only to fix something if wrong or redundant.

```
...
else if ((emailList != null) && (emailTest != null) 
                  && (emailTest.compareTo(IParameterNames.EMAIL_GO) == 0))  // #1 One of the AND conditions to enter this "else if" block is: "emailList != null",
              {                                                             // #2 so if "emailList != null" is not "true" we wouldn't even be in this "else if" block.

                response.getOutputStream().print("...blah blah blah...");
                response.getOutputStream().print("...blah blah blah...");
                response.getOutputStream().print("...blah blah blah...");

                if (emailList != null)  //#3 Here we check again if primary condition is fulfilled: "emailList != null". 
                                        //#4 If "emailList != null" is not "true" we wouldn't even be in this "else if" block.This should be removed IMHO
                {
                  response.getOutputStream().print(emailList.size());
                }
                else //#5 And as "emailList != null" was true at the else if here it can't be different than that. This should be removed IMHO as it is DEAD CODE.
                {
                  response.getOutputStream().print("0 ");
                }

                response.getOutputStream().print("...blah blah blah...");
                response.getOutputStream().print("...blah blah blah...");

                if (emailList != null)  //#6 Here we check again if primary condition is fulfilled: "emailList != null". 
                                        //#7 If "emailList != null" is not "true" we wouldn't even be in this "else if" block.This should be removed IMHO
                {
                  response
                      .getOutputStream()
                      .print("...blah blah blah...");

                  for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++)
                  {
                    email = (EmailMessage) emailList.get(i);

                    if (email != null)
                    {
                      response.getOutputStream().print(outputEmailAddressAsHTML(email, i).toString());
                    }
                  }
                }

                response.getOutputStream().print("..lots.of.blah blah blah...");
              }
...
```

Comment: Where/How is the `emailList` variable set? Can it ever be changed? Is this a multithreaded environment? If not, then you are right. If it can be set to null by another thread, then chaos can happen. (but then you'd need some synchronization here anyways really...)

Comment: Your questions are valid, but answer to them is: no. As you noticed otherwise synchronization would be necessary. Code works (not only this piece but whole application) but it's a kinda mess, so I am "cleaning" it bit by bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assessment is correct, the `emailList` null checks are redundant in that block.

I would recommend that you [use the "FindBugs" tool](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to perform static analysis on your code. It is available as a plugin to Eclipse, and other tools too. FindBugs would clearly indicate and mark all instances where these problems happen, and also a bunch of other things too.

Additionally, I would neaten things up by pulling just one final local variable for the `response.getOutputStream()` too. Additionally, you should be using generics, and enhanced-for (for-each) loops over your `emailList`.

Summarizing this would be:

```
...
else if ((emailList != null) && (emailTest != null) 
              && (emailTest.compareTo(IParameterNames.EMAIL_GO) == 0))               
         {

            PrintOutputStream respos = response.getOutputStream();
            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");
            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");
            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");

            respos.print(emailList.size());

            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");
            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");

            respos.print("...blah blah blah...");

            for (EmailMessage email : emailList) {
                if (email != null) {
                  respos.print(outputEmailAddressAsHTML(email, i).toString());
                }
            }

            respos.print("..lots.of.blah blah blah...");
          }
```

Comment: another great tool for finding such things is sonar / sonarqube, which also gives your boss "hard metrics" of technical debt in your codebase...

Comment: Am I wrong or "i" in (email, i) now becomes "undeclared" respos.print(outputEmailAddressAsHTML(email, i).toString());

Comment: @NenadBulatovic - you are correct. The `i` is now undeclared, and is an oversight in my "refactor". Reverting to a regular `for` loop will restore the `i` variable, but you should still have a generic `emailList` which would make the explicit cast to `EmailMessage` unnecessary.